# How to temporary remove all cookies in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browsing

What i want to do is simulate what a new internet user sees. If i make a youtube search, for example, the results are different for me (they are base on the history of my activity on youtube, i think). I want to be able to see what would be the results of a new person.

So how can i temporary delete cookies and browsing information ?

---

Private browsing seem to be a good solution, but I believe this is what happens when i use private browsing: when i start a private session, chromes makes a snapshots of all browsing files (doanwloads, cache, cookies, history...), and when i stop this session, chromes restores the snapshop made before. I think that when i start the session, chrome doesn't delete anything. (Can you confirm that ?)

---

**Edit :** I was confused by the fact that all incognito windows share the same cookie jar. What I did is that I already had a few open, and open one more: the new one inherits all the previous PHP_SESSID, so the same server sessions. **If you want all cookies to be removed, close ALL incognito windows, and open a new one.** Issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690

Comment: I think you're wrong, as starting an incognito session does NOT log me in to Super User. What are your test results?

Comment: No. When you start an incognito session, you get a new window which practically starts "blank", i.e. without any cookies stored or anything like that, additionally your addons are disabled. While you use the window, cookies are stored only temporarily and limited to that window. When you close the incognito window, the cache and cookies are gone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could always move the config files but I believe it would be cleaner and simpler to create a new real OS user and delete it after testing.

Comment: Additional advantage: this way the browser won't use existing Flash Local Shared Objects. (Aka Flash cookies; shared across browsers per user, and not cleared in all browsers when cookies etc. are removed.)